# How to reference a specific ENUM value in GraphQL type?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have the following schema:

```
enum PaymentTypeName {
  PAYMENT_CARD
  PAYMENT_CARD_TOKEN
}

interface Payment {
  id: ID!
  type: PaymentTypeName!
}

type PaymentCardPayment implements Payment {
  id: ID!
  type: PaymentTypeName!
  card: PaymentCard!
}

type PaymentCardTokenPayment implements Payment {
  id: ID!
  type: PaymentTypeName!
  card: PaymentCard!
}
```

When `Payment` is `PaymentCardPayment` or `PaymentCardTokenPayment` is determined by the value of type, i.e. it is either `PAYMENT_CARD` or `PAYMENT_CARD_TOKEN`.

How do I signify in the interface, that `PaymentCardPayment`/ `PaymentCardTokenPayment` inherit a specific value of `PaymentTypeName`?

I have tried various combinations of:

```
type PaymentCardPayment implements Payment {
  id: ID!
  type: PaymentTypeName.PAYMENT_CARD!
  card: PaymentCard!
}
```

and:

```
type PaymentCardPayment implements Payment {
  id: ID!
  type: PaymentTypeName[PAYMENT_CARD]!
  card: PaymentCard!
}
```

but all of these prompt a syntax error and I was unable to find the relevant documentation.

Comment: did you find some sort of a solution?

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is not supported in GraphQL. If a field's type is declared to be `PaymentTypeName`, and `PAYMENT_CARD` and `PAYMENT_CARD_TOKEN` are both valid values of `PaymentTypeName`, then they must also be valid values for that field. There is no way to take an existing type9 whether it's an enum, scalar, or object type) and conditionally create a subset of possible values from the set of possible values already defined by the type.

That said, if `PaymentCardPayment.type` will always resolve to `PAYMENT_CARD` and `PaymentCardTokenPayment.type` will always resolve to `PAYMENT_CARD_TOKEN`, then it doesn't really make sense to use an enum here at all. In fact, in this specific case, we can omit the `type` field entirely. After all, the only purpose of the field in this case is to allow the client to distinguish between the possible types that `Payment` may resolve to. However, GraphQL already provides us with a [__typename](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Type-Name-Introspection) field that does just that by resolving to the name of the resolved type.

So in this specific instance, it's sufficient to just do:

```
interface Payment {
  id: ID!
}

type PaymentCardPayment implements Payment {
  id: ID!
  card: PaymentCard!
}

type PaymentCardTokenPayment implements Payment {
  id: ID!
  card: PaymentCard!
}
```

and query a field whose type is `Payment` like this:

```
{
  payments {
    id
    __typename
    ... on PaymentCardPayment {
      card {
        # ...
      }
    }
    ... on PaymentCardTokenPayment {
      card {
        # ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to declare the field *value* in your type schema, which is not what a schema is meant for. You should only be declaring your field **type** within your schema, in this case it is just `type: PaymentTypeName`. You have it correct in your first code block.

Your `PaymentCardPayment`'s `type` resolver function should return the value of the enum, in your case, `PAYMENT_CARD`.

Your `PaymentCardTokenPayment`'s `type` resolver function should return the value of `PAYMENT_CARD_TOKEN`.

Comment: I disagree. ENUM is a special case. `PaymentType` context it makes sense that `type` can inherit any of the `PaymentTypeName` values. However, in the context of `PaymentCardPayment` it is misleading to say that the value is either of the ENUM values; it is not. It is a constant value thats a subset of `PaymentTypeName`.

Comment: Have to agree, refining that the subset will always be a static value from the `ENUM` that the interface guarantees makes sense and is likely one of the common ways that `ENUM` would be used when not being used for filtering via input types.

Comment: So have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This only works on input types.

```
enum PaymentTypeName {
  PAYMENT_CARD
  WAD_OF_CASH
} 
 
input BuySomethingInput {
  method: PaymentTypeName! = WAD_OF_CASH
  price: Number
}
```

and then use the input type in a Mutation.

> The following is not going to work

Would using a default value work for you?

```
type PaymentCardPayment implements Payment {
  id: ID!
  type: PaymentTypeName! = PAYMENT_CARD
  card: PaymentCard!
}
```

It won't prevent you from overwriting the value but at least it should be set correctly.

Comment: This would be great. But I get a syntax error - are you sure this works?

Comment: My mistake - this only works on input types. I'm updating the answer.